# Setting & Accessing $cookies in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have been using $rootScope to save data in my angular app uptil now, but when user refreshes the page the data is lost. Need to change that.

**Login Controller**

```
myapp.controller('loginController', function($scope, $rootScope, loginFactory, requestFactory, userFactory, contactFactory, $location, $cookies) {

        $scope.getUser = function(){
            delete $rootScope.reqMessage;
            var user_repack = {
                email: $scope.user.email,
                password: $scope.user.password
            }
            loginFactory.getUser(user_repack, function (data){
                $rootScope.users = data
                $scope.userData = $cookies.userData || {};
                $cookies.userData = data
            requestFactory.getRecievedRequests(data, function (data){
                    if(data.length > 0){
                    $rootScope.recievedRequests = data;
                }
                })
            contactFactory.getContacts(data, function (data){
                $rootScope.userContacts = data;
            })
                $location.path('/dashboard')
            })
        }
});
```

**Injecting ngCookies**

```
var myapp = angular.module('demo_app', ['ngRoute', 'ngMessages', 'ngCookies']);

    });
```

**Front End**

```
<div ng-controller="userController" ng-show="users">
<div class="pull-right" ng-controller="loginController">
            <form>
            <input type='submit' value='Logout' ng-click='logout()' class="btn btn-danger">
        </form>
 </div>
 <h5 ng-show="welcome">{{welcome}}</h5>
<h2>Hello {{users.name}} {{userData}}</h2>
```

I have used both $rootScope and $cookies just to try it out. In the front end users.name prints but not userData.

Been trying to figure this out for a while now. any help is appreciated. Thank you.

PS: Im aware this Q has been asked before, i've read through the other posts but couldn't figure it out.

Edit

have tried following the get & put method from the documentation.

```
var userCookie = $cookies.get('userCookie')
                $cookies.put('userCookie', data);
```

throws an error saying $cookies.get is not a function

Comment: ``$cookies`` should be used with the ``get`` and ``put`` methods. Refer to the document : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: I have tried that get & out methods as well following the documentation. dint work, looked on here and found this way